# How to conditionally apply a filter in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a bit new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm wondering if there is a framework construct that can do what I have described below?:

I would like to apply a filter to a group of controllers/actions based off of some arbitrary criteria.  The key point here is that I want to apply the filters only to certain controllers or actions based on this criteria.  I do NOT want to use an attribute on the controller or the controller action as developers may forget to add these attributes to the controller actions.

This link basically describes what I want: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx

I'm wondering, though, is there an ASP.NET MVC framework construct I can use to do this without having to roll my own?  I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 by the way.

Thanks very much, sorry if this isn't clear!

Comment: That approach *IS* an MVC framework construct.  It's specifically implementing an IFilterProvider, which is an extensibility mechanism designed into the MVC framework to allow you to customize the way things work.  In other words, you're using the framework as it's intended to be used.

Comment: @MystereMan, Thanks, that is what I figured.  I guess I'm used to other MVC frameworks which have a little bit more functionality around filters.  It isn't too hard to write our own implementation though.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create your own conditional filter, there isn't any other way of conditionally applying an attribute on a controller action.

The haacked approach you supplied is the way to do it.